# $.active will be always 1 if ajax call throws unexpected error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

I have a method which blocks the UI until an ajax response is received. So adding 1 second to the timer and blocking the loader until `$.active == true`, which means no pending ajax requests.

But, the issue here is, if any jquery error/ajax error throws and is not handled, `$.active` will always be 1. The application is blocked with an image and never becomes true. Any idea what's the alternative or solution for this issue?

```js
function startLoader(timeout, delay) {
    loader = setTimeout(function() {
        $.blockUI({
          message: '<img "a.png" alt="Loader"/>',
        });
    }, delay /*loader delay*/ );
    checkPendingRequest();
}

function checkPendingRequest() {
    if ($.active > 0) {
        window.setTimeout(checkPendingRequest, 1000);
    } else {
        stopLoaderAjax();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle it is using the [ajaxStart](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxStop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) functions

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $.blockUI({
        message: '<img "a.png" alt="Loader"/>',
    });
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    $.unblockUI();
});
```

These will automatically be fired at the start and end of all your ajax calls and include errors.

Comment: then why in any application framework, generic loader function requires timeout?

Comment: I am not sure what frameworks you mean, this timeout may be to stop very short ajax requests from causing the loader to come up. 
I use the above code in my applications and have no problem with it

Comment: I tried the above in my application.. But again loader will never stop, if one ajax calls another ajax and receives unhandled error such as loadTime(); where loadTime() is not a method.